# Memory filled with Xarray concat function

Tags: python, rioxarray, xarray

I'm facing in trouble related to the limit of my RAM. On my PC I have 32GB of RAM that is totaly filled from the `concat` of some `DataArray`.

I've create e simple function below to read a single band of Sentinel 2 scene and put all into a list:

```
dataarray_list = []
for band_code, band_data in tqdm(scene_bands.items()):

    band = rioxarray.open_rasterio(
        filename=band_data["path"],
        chunks={'x': 512, 'y': 512}
    )

    dataarray_list.append(band)
```

`scene_bands` is a dictionary with band code, path and description.

Now I'm tring to create a `Dataset`:

```
dataset = xarray.concat(dataarray_list, dim='band_code')
```

Here the error of filled memory:

> Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)

Is there a way to execute the concat from disk instead of memory?
If you have another approach share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem using [xarray.open_mfdataset](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_mfdataset.html#xarray.open_mfdataset) instead of rioxarray.open_rasterio.

```
    band = xarray.open_mfdataset(
        paths=file_path,
        chunks={'x': 512, 'y': 512},
        parallel=True,
    )
```

With that function I'm be able to create the final dataset without problems:

```
dataset = xarray.concat(dataarray_list, dim='band_code')
```