# GeoTIFF from Dataset is very weight and with three bands instead of one

Tags: python, rioxarray, xarray

I need to compute the NDVI from an xarray Dataset created using [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/462059/72195). I've used a for loop to read all the GeoTIFFs in my folder and the result is this:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (band: 3, x: 16470, y: 16470, time: 1, common_name: 16)
Coordinates:
  * band         (band) int64 1 2 3
  * x            (x) float64 4e+05 4e+05 4e+05 ... 5.097e+05 5.098e+05 5.098e+05
  * y            (y) float64 4.49e+06 4.49e+06 4.49e+06 ... 4.6e+06 4.6e+06
    spatial_ref  int64 0
  * common_name  (common_name) <U8 'aot' 'coastal' 'blue' ... 'scl' 'wvp' 'tci'
  * time         (time) datetime64[ns] 2022-07-09T10:00:29.024000
Data variables:
    band_data    (time, common_name, band, y, x) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 1, 3, 342, 768), meta=np.ndarray>
Attributes:
    platform:  Sentinel-2B
    epsg:      32633
```

With the code below I can be able to compute the index from the bands stored inside the Dataset:

```
    # Get red band
    red = data.sel(common_name='red')

    # Get nir band
    nir = data.sel(common_name='nir08')

    # Compute index
    index = (nir - red) / (nir + red)

    # Add coordinates
    index = index.assign_coords(index='NDVI')
    index = index.expand_dims(dim='index')
    index = index.assign_coords(platform=data.attrs['platform'])
    index = index.expand_dims(dim='platform')
```

When I try to save the result as GeoTiff the weight of the output file is very big, over 3.3GB for only one scene (only one day). This is the first strange thing, the second is that I can't see the content of the image that has three bands when I would have expected only one band.

I've used the code below to make the file:

```
        dataarray = index.to_array().squeeze()
        dataarray = dataarray.drop_vars('band')

        output_data = output_folder.joinpath('ndvi.tif')
        dataarray.astype('float32').rio.to_raster(output_data, driver="GTiff")
```

What am I doing wrong?

**NB:** I need to use a Dataset because NDVI is only one of more indexes that I need to compute, so, it's useful for me to have all bands inside one object.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have xarrays, why not use Spyndex for the calculations!? Its surprisingly easy, fast, and if you have all the necessary bands you just list the indices you want and the accompanying parameters. The example below is adapted from the [Spyndex documentation](https://spyndex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/started.html#how-does-it-work).

```
import spyndex
import xarray as xr

# Open a dataset (in this case a xarray.DataArray)
da = xr.DataArray(np.array([NIR,RED,BLUE,GREEN]),
                  dims = ("band","x","y"),
                  coords = {"band": ["NIR","Red","Blue","Green"]})

# Compute the desired spectral indices
idx = spyndex.computeIndex(
      index = ["NDVI","GNDVI","SAVI"],
      params = {"N": da.sel(band = "NIR"),
          "R": da.sel(band = "Red"),
          "G": da.sel(band = "Green"),
          "L": 0.5})
```

From there, you could export your indices individually or as a multi-dimensional raster. As for the filesize increase, it could be a number of things, but you might check to make the nodata value explicit when writing to file.